# Failed to get SiteURL when connecting webex XML api using .net

Tags: .net, webex

I have creating simple .net console application and I am calling webex service to create meeting.

But I got failure with message "Failed to get SiteURL"

Can anyone told why I am getting this error message.

Service I am calling : https://apidemoeu.webex.com/WBXService/XMLService

Answer (score 0):

Please check for Valid site Name or ID. your site name should match the sub-domain of your WebEx URL, in this case it should be apidemoeu based on your POST URL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But problem was not related wot any URL everything was perfect just xml was not compliance with xml definition . Problamtic tag was :         <maxusernumber>4</maxusernumber>